# Symfony: getting form values before and after form handling

Tags: forms, symfony

Hello I want to be able to compare values before and after form handling, so that I can process them before flush.
What I do is collect old values in an array before handlerequest.
I then compare new values to the old values in the array.

It works perfectly on simple variables, like strings for instance.
However I want to work on uploaded files. I am able to get their fullpath and names before handling the form but when I get the values after checking if form is valid, I am still getting the same old value.

I tried both calling $entity->getVar() and $form->getData()->getVar() and I have the same output....

Comment: how are you handling the files in your entities

Comment: Also filenames are really not the best comparison for the files, you should run the contents of themm through a checksum like sha1 and compare those outputs

Comment: Probably want to clone your entity then use the cloned copy for your before values. http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.cloning.php

Answer (score 0):

Hello I actually found a solution. Yet it is a departure from the strategy announced in my question, which I realize is somewhat truncated regarding my objective. Which was to compare  old file names and new names (those names actually include full path) for changes, so that I would unlink those of those old names that were not in the new name list anymore. Basically, to operate a cleanup after a file was uploaded to replace another, without the first one being deleted first. And to save the webmaster the hassle of having to sort between uniqid-named files that are still used by the web site and those that are useless.
Problem is that my upload functions, that are very similar to those given in examples to the file upload code shown on the official documentation pages, seemed to take effect at flush time. 
So, since what I wanted to do with those files had nothing to do with database operations, I resorted to having step two  code launch after flush, which works fine.
However I am intrigued by your solutions, as they are both strategies I hadn't thought of.  Thank you for suggestions.

However I am not sure if cloning the whole object will be as straightforward as comparing two arrays of file names.

Comment: I should precise that my understanding of how Symfony/Doctrine works is somewhat fuzzy. When I code in pure php I have a much clearer understanding of what's going on. With symfony it's more like try, observe and learn. I am using lifecycle callbacks and the code that generates a uniqid generated name is called at pre-persist/pre-update stage, The update is brought about by a setUpdatedAt method in setFile. that is why I was assuming that  the new generated name would be accessible right after form was handled,